# subtract a value from an array efficiently in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, click

I have an 2-dim array representing the arrival times of photons in two channels, the array contains a line with the information about the arrival time and the other with the information about the timestamp

```
  data = stream.getData();
    timestamps = data.getTimestamps();
    channels = data.getChannels();
    timetags = [timestamps; channels];
    t= [timetags];
```

I need a start-multiple stop measurments, so when there is a click in the channel 1 I need to subtract the timestamp for that click in every timestamp of channel 2, until the next click in channel 1 and so on. I used a for cicle for this:

```
for i=1:length(t)
    if t(2,i)==1
        t(1,i:end)=t(1,i:end)-t(1,i)
    end
end
```

but it is quite slow. Is there a faster way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `t(2,:)==0` to create an array which is true on your condition, then `t(1,:).*(t(2,:)==0)` gives either `0` or the current timestamp when this is true.

Therefore, if `t(2,:)` is non-decreasing you should be able to do something like

```
t(1,:) = t(1,:) - cummax( t(1,:) .* (t(2,:)==0) );
```